# HQL:How to make Not Exists Query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, hql

I have a ManyToMany relationship between "utilisateur" and "projet"
and I want to extract all the users not existing  in the project entity
then this is my query:

```
Query req=utilisateurDAO.createQuery("select u from utilisateur u where not in(select p from projet p where p.utilisateurs.iduser=u.iduser) ");
```

and this is  "Projet" entity:

```
        @Entity
        public class Projet implements Serializable {
             @Column(name = "idprojet", nullable = false)
             @Id
             @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
             Integer idprojet;
             @ManyToMany(mappedBy="projets", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
             java.util.List<com.gestion.projet.domain.Utilisateur> utilisateurs;
    }
```

and this the "Utilisateur" Entity

```
 @Entity
        public class Utilisateur implements Serializable {
             @Column(name = "iduser", nullable = false)
             @Id
             @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
             Integer iduser;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(schema = "public", name = "join_membre_projet", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "iduser", referencedColumnName = "iduser", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idprojet", referencedColumnName = "idprojet", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    java.util.List<com.gestion.projet.domain.Projet> projets;
}
```

and i dont know why does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HQL supports both [sub selects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries) as well as collection expressions.

All the users not existing in the project entity means all users who have no project assigned or users with an empty project list:

```
select u from Utilisateur where u.projets is empty
```

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries